# PHP issue using a method's return value as a parameter for query function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function query:

```
function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;

//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);

//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();

    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
    }
```

The function works just fine when I use it like this:

```
$g = "05%";
$result = query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_column LIKE '%s'", $g);
print json_encode($result);
```

However I am getting no result when $g is a value retrieved from a method. For example lets say I have a method getMonth() from a class Date that returns the current month of May as 05% when echoed. I try the code below and get nothing from the database:

```
$time = new Date();
//$g = "05%"; this would definitely get results from the db
$h = $time->getMonth();
echo $h; //this displays 05% on the screen
$result = query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_column LIKE '%s'", $h);
print json_encode($result);
```

I am pretty sure that I am making a simple mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out. How can I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Print `$sql` in `query` function and see what it contains

Comment: Where does the mythical `%` come from when you do `$h = $time->getMonth();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something that your method return only 05 part from 05%. and append % after that for example

```
$h = $time->getMonth(); 
$h = "$h%";
```

and then it should work

Comment: I guess what was missing was using your second line of code and turning $h into "$h". Thanks a lot it is now working.